# .htaccess URL to lowercase

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, lowercase

How to alter following snippet of .htaccess file to achieve:

Now if it rewrites, it takes user from-to:

```
domain.com/TEST - domain.com/test
domain.com/subdir/TEST - domain.com/test
```

Needed behaeviour is:

> ```
> domain.com/TEST - domain.com/test
> domain.com/subdir/TEST - domain.com/subdir/test
> ```

Unwanted behaeviour occurs when webpage's index is at 'subdir' directory, instead directly under domain.com, as shown in first example above.

```
# URL to lowercase
# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Explain: "when webpage's index is at 'subdir' directory"

Comment: If I'm in subdirectory of domain it redirects back to domain ommiting a dir. This line is responsible for it I suppose, yet need help altering it `RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]` - see first example

Comment: Have you kept any `.htaccess` in sub dirs as well? Also, it's incorrect to use the word 'index' for just about any file because it refers to a location like `/` or a landing page inside a directory like `subdir/index.php`.

Comment: htaccess is recursive, no need to keep it in sub dirs. I use 'index' in my own way, yet it's not an matter of that question.

Comment: I know that. I asked if you have it inside subdir because only then your rule `/$` would remove `subdir` from the URL. From the root it would leave your URL unchanged.

Comment: Well yes my .htacces is in subdir, as well as website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, remove the `.htaccess` present inside `/subdir` because then your rule `/$` would remove `subdir` from the input URL since that leading `/` makes it an absolute URL. From the root `.htaccess`, the rule would leave the URL unchanged (except changing the case).

Alternatively, if you have any sub-directory specific rules and want to keep your `/subdir/.htaccess` just change it's rule to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]`.

Comment: Damn I am sure was testing this solution and wasn't working. CnPing your alternative solution (that's what I was looking for) does it's job. Thnx!